# why when I use Inlineformset do I have many fields diplayed in template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm beginner on django and I try to use and understand how an single page, It is possible to display questions from a model and response from another model which is related to the first with a FK. So, I use inlineformset in my views, but in my template I have 4 fields with the same label.

my models.py

```
class Studiesquestion(models.Model):
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    question = models.TextField(null=False)
    information = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    

class Studiesresponse(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Studiesquestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

my view

```
def marketstudiesResponse(request):
    question = Studiesquestion.objects.get(pk=3)
    BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Studiesquestion, Studiesresponse, fields = ["response"])
    print(BookFormSet)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, instance=question)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            print("ok")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        formset = BookFormSet(instance=question)
        print(formset)

    return render(request, "marketing/marketstudiesResponse.html", {'formset': formset })
```

my template

```
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{formset.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    </form>
```

my html do it

```
<form method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="GtyCWorBXXzGWz5qYTC2GZfREjPMqmFZyn0n4yIgCqpVb5E1JMSJs5maeuJcdrjW">
        <input type="hidden" name="studiesresponse_set-TOTAL_FORMS" value="3" id="id_studiesresponse_set-TOTAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="studiesresponse_set-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0" id="id_studiesresponse_set-INITIAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="studiesresponse_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" id="id_studiesresponse_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="studiesresponse_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_studiesresponse_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS">
<p><label for="id_studiesresponse_set-0-response">Response:</label> <textarea name="studiesresponse_set-0-response" cols="40" rows="10" id="id_studiesresponse_set-0-response"></textarea></p>
<p><label for="id_studiesresponse_set-0-DELETE">Delete:</label> <input type="checkbox" name="studiesresponse_set-0-DELETE" id="id_studiesresponse_set-0-DELETE"><input type="hidden" name="studiesresponse_set-0-id" id="id_studiesresponse_set-0-id"><input type="hidden" name="studiesresponse_set-0-question" value="3" id="id_studiesresponse_set-0-question"></p> <p><label for="id_studiesresponse_set-1-response">Response:</label> <textarea name="studiesresponse_set-1-response" cols="40" rows="10" id="id_studiesresponse_set-1-response"></textarea></p>
<p><label for="id_studiesresponse_set-1-DELETE">Delete:</label> <input type="checkbox" name="studiesresponse_set-1-DELETE" id="id_studiesresponse_set-1-DELETE"><input type="hidden" name="studiesresponse_set-1-id" id="id_studiesresponse_set-1-id"><input type="hidden" name="studiesresponse_set-1-question" value="3" id="id_studiesresponse_set-1-question"></p> <p><label for="id_studiesresponse_set-2-response">Response:</label> <textarea name="studiesresponse_set-2-response" cols="40" rows="10" id="id_studiesresponse_set-2-response"></textarea></p>
<p><label for="id_studiesresponse_set-2-DELETE">Delete:</label> <input type="checkbox" name="studiesresponse_set-2-DELETE" id="id_studiesresponse_set-2-DELETE"><input type="hidden" name="studiesresponse_set-2-id" id="id_studiesresponse_set-2-id"><input type="hidden" name="studiesresponse_set-2-question" value="3" id="id_studiesresponse_set-2-question"></p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    </form>
```

I really don't understand.

I don't know if a method is more appropriate to my project or if I did a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each form in your formset only has one field `response`, the label for each form will be the same.

Also use `{{formset.management_form }}` which is responsible for managing the formset data and keeping track of the number of forms in the formset.

Try to use looping syntax which renders each field individually and loop over each form in the formset, try to do something like following:

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="{{ form.response.id_for_label }}">{{ form.question.title }}</label>
            {{ form.response }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also set `extra` parameter to `0` so:

```py
def marketstudiesResponse(request):
    question = Studiesquestion.objects.get(pk=3)
    BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Studiesquestion, Studiesresponse, fields = ["response"], extra=0)
    print(BookFormSet)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, instance=question)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            print("ok")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        formset = BookFormSet(instance=question)
        print(formset)

    return render(request, "marketing/marketstudiesResponse.html", {'formset': formset })
```

Comment: Yes i tried but I still have four boxes and four `response` fields in my html. I wrote your code but I'm not able to understand why do I have as many as response fields. I have only one question in my db so I should have only one  `response` field.

Comment: thank you, i put extra=0 and it works :)